# Dovecot auth-worker logs fails but log in works

Tags: dovecot, pam, imap

Everytime a log in occurs I get three log lines:

```
Mar 19 15:29:05 auth-worker(6379): Info: pam(golf@email.com,124.1.1.1,<AL/fkjf3yr98xTrl>): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (Password mismatch?)
Mar 19 15:29:05 auth-worker(6379): Info: passwd(golf@email.com,124.1.1.1,<AL/fkjf3yr98xTrl>): unknown user
Mar 19 15:29:05 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<golf@email.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=124.1.1.1, lip=1.1.1.1, mpid=6387, TLS, session=<AL/fkjf3yr98xTrl>
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening here? Why does pam and passwd fail at first but the log in does work?

Comment: Possibly because you have other mechanisms than PAM defined. Unless you show us your configuration, we can't know.

Comment: Usually `pam` is setup in such a way that for each *service* there is a separate file in `/etc/pam.d` - your *login* or *ssh* service configuration may differ from the defaults for *dovecot*.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple userdb entries in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-system.conf.ext

```
userdb {
 driver = passwd
}

userdb {
 driver = pam
}
```

I removed them both and now it only uses sql driver for userdb which was listed in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext